# Explaining some points in the proof of proposition 2 pg. 55 in Royden.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proposition and its proof are given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1-I do not understand the proof in the first line and half, why since each interval $(c, \infty)$ is open the function $f$ is measurable?

2- why $\mathcal{O}$ can be written as the union of **bounded** intervals? and are those intervals disjoint? if so, why we want them disjoint? if not, why we do not want them disjoint ?

Could anyone help me in answering this question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It  is an ''if and only if'' statement,so in the first line he assumes that the inverse of an open set is measurable.

It is a fact that on the real line every open set can be written as a countable union of open disjoint intervals $I_n$

You can make these intervals bounded considering the intervals $I_{m,n}=I_n \cap (-m,m)$ where $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$.

In general it does not matter if we take the intervals whose union is an open set disjoint or not for this proof.

Comment: why the author chooses this interval $(c, \infty)$ specifically?

Comment: Because in the definition of the measurability of a functions we have that a function on the real line is measurable if $f^{-1}(c,+\infty)$ is measurable for every $c \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you very much ..... if you have time could you look at this please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367168/a-small-discussion-about-proposition-1-in-chapter-3-in-royden?noredirect=1#comment6929354_3367168

Comment: For this,just read the comments in the post..they answer your question..